# Display data from database in src image in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a database that stores the images file name. For example `image1.jpg`

The actual image is saved in a folder in the root directory in the `/images` folder.

I want to retrieve the file name and to add it to the  image code in ASP.net

`<asp:Image ID="VegImg1" runat="server" Height="146px" Width="274px" />`

I currently have code calling in its information but unsure how to call in the image and use that as its filepath.

***C#***

```
private void loadRecipe()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True ORDER BY NEWID()");
            con.Open();
            try
                {
                    //Fetching top recipe     
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select top 1 percent Recipe_Name, Recipe_Description FROM Recipe", con);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        VeganLbl1.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                        descriptionLbl1.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();

                }
            catch (Exception)
                {



                }

            con.Close();
        }
```

***ASP.NET***

```
 <li class="three">
            <h5>Vegan Recipes<br />
            </h5>
            <table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
                <td class="auto-style5">
                    <asp:Label ID="VeganLbl3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                  </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">&lt;Link Here&gt;</td>      
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="auto-style6">
            <asp:Image ID="VegImg3" runat="server" Height="146px" Width="274px" />
                  </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="descriptionLbl3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                  </td>     
              </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
        </li>
```

Comment: You can't attached multiple copies of a database to the server.  The database file is an mdb file and should already be attached.  You reference a database by its attached name (not the mdf filename). The attached name is usally the same as the mdf file without the mdf extension.  You should connect to the database by the server name.  You can specify the default database in the connection string.  If you want to use another database in the server other than the default than in the SQL statement add a 'USE New_DataBase_name' where New_DataBase_name is the name of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming That Image is store in same table

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select top 1 percent Recipe_Name, Recipe_Description,ImageColumnName FROM Recipe", con);
```

After Fetching ImageNameColumn Value

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
       VeganLbl1.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
       descriptionLbl1.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
       VegImg1.ImageUrl=String.Format("//Image//{0}",dt.Rows[0][2].ToString());
 }
```

Comment: this isnt working. no errors but no image is showing. Yet the file path is correct and so is the image file name. Its showing an X when the image should be.

Comment: I debugged it and its stating its bringing back the correct name. spicyfood.jpg

Comment: @DonaldBury try to add exact path in `String.Format("//Image//{0}",dt.Rows[0][2].ToString());`